# Can a S.Korean game have the right to steal money and items and close your acct for no reason?

Tags: theft

I have played Kalonline since 2012.  You use real money to get virtual money to use in the game to purchase items.  I simply tried to change a password on one of my 3 accts.(which they encourage us to do) and they blocked all my accts. The items and virtual money is worth a lot in US currency.  They ignore my messages, and e-mails...Is there anything I can do?  Thanks so much, L.Kupau

Answer (score 2):

As with any online service, read the various Terms of Service agreements you "click" signed as a contract when you started using the service: http://kalonline.gameagit.com/Customer/CashStipulation.asp?btn=2 and http://kalonline.gameagit.com/Customer/Stipulation.asp?btn=1

Those agreements outline your rights as well as your agreement with the service's policies regarding closing accounts, refund policies and any requirements for arbitration.

The service may have disabled account access since they think the account are hacked, or they think you are hacking, or any other reason outlined in the agreements.

Companies generally have motivation to be fair, as they won't want bad PR about their service. Hopefully they eventually respond to you about your accounts.

But, aside from those agreements, if indeed the service has unfairly taken payments and refuses to give a refund or access to your accounts again, the service is based in South Korea, so you have little recourse unless you hire legal representation.

Comment: Appreciate this fast answer so much!!!